# LE12CZ connected to 5V outputs wrong voltage

Tags: voltage-regulator

I connected a [LE12CZ regulator](https://mouser.com/ProductDetail/STMicroelectronics/LE12CZ?qs=htKRmzjvioS5a3Boe%2FHoig%3D%3D) (TO-92) to a breadboard.

Input voltage: 5 V
Expected output voltage: 1.25 V
Real output voltage: 4.05 V

Pins connection (before EDIT):

1. 5 V
2. GND
3. Voltage meter (output)

Pins connection:

1. Voltage meter (output)
2. GND
3. 5 V

I tried to use another one; same results. Even connecting the suggested capacitors on input/output didn't drop the voltage.

What could be wrong? Am I reading the datasheet wrong?

Comment: You might have mistakenly wired it incorrectly. Easy to get wrong with the ambiguity in this obsolete part's data sheet.

Comment: Thanks for review, thats my mistake when I was writing it down. Connection was correct. Triple checked

Comment: once a formal answer is given, you have to be very careful in making edits to your original question because now, you have invalidated Spehro's answer. You need to pay proper heed to that answer so that his answer doesn't appear to be wrong and attract downvotes from people not taking the time to read your question history. Please fix your question to make that clear.

Comment: Thanks for tip, fixed original question

Answer (score 0):

Your connection pin numbers do not seem to match the datasheet you linked., for either TO-92 or SO-8. Seems like you've swapped Vin and Vout.

[image]

You do definitely need the capacitors, particularly the output capacitor in the recommended range, as this is an LDO. Note the lower end of the  ESR range which would preclude the use of ceramic capacitors in most cases.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for noticing my pin are switched.. however just in topic, not on breadboard, my mistake during writing it down.